# How to make telegram bots send messages to the forum topic and not to general chat

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, sendmessage

Idk how it work. I try this code, but the bot sends a message to the wrong place.
Maybe the topic has some special arguments?
Whatever I try to do, all messages are sent to the general topic.

```
import os
import asyncio
from typing import Optional
from telegram import ForumTopic
from telegram import Bot, Message
import time

class AsyncBotClient:
    def __init__(self, bot_token: str):
        self.bot = Bot(token=bot_token)

    async def send_message(
        self,
        chat_id: str,
        text: str,
        *,
        parse_mode: Optional[str] = None,
        disable_web_page_preview: Optional[bool] = None,
        disable_notification: Optional[bool] = None,
        reply_to_message_id: Optional[int] = None,
        api_kwargs: Optional[dict] = None,
    ) -> Message:
        return await self.bot.send_message(
            chat_id=chat_id,
            text=text,
            parse_mode=parse_mode,
            disable_web_page_preview=disable_web_page_preview,
            disable_notification=disable_notification,
            reply_to_message_id=reply_to_message_id,
            api_kwargs=api_kwargs,
        )

async def main():
    bot_token = ""
    async_bot_client = AsyncBotClient(bot_token)
    topic_id = "-1002124######_33903"
    message_text = "test"
    await async_bot_client.send_message(chat_id=topic_id, text=message_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed the telegram bot documentation and realized that I was missing the msg_thread_id argument that each of the created topics has.